# Xcode command line upload/download files to/from an iOS Device Application Sandbox

Tags: ios, xcode, automation, jenkins, continuous-integration

does someone of you know, how I can mange the file transfer of my App data like the Organizer from the command line? I tried to find a way with xcrun or Instruments, but currently without success.

My goal is to run acceptance tests on the device by jenkins. Currently I'm able to upload a new version of my app and start it by Instruments. But a way for reseting the client data or push modified data to test them is missing.

Thanks,
Thomas

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you found a solution?

Comment: Not really, I added command line option support to my app for resetting, but pushing earlier saved data is still an open issue.

Answer (score 5):

In the info.plist you can add the key: **Application supports iTunes file sharing** and set it to **YES**.
Then you be able to manage your app data using the iTunes. Open iTunes, go to your device and open the application tab.

Down in this page go to file sharing section and there you have your app Documents folder to pass all you data.

I hope this result useful.

Comment: Thanks for this. But I'm looking for a solution which could be completely automated. My goal is to run UI automation tests with Jenkins on the device and reset all data before running a new test.

Comment: @ThWee I'm sure it's too late now but what Fede suggested is part of the solution you need. First you need to have iTunes file sharing on, and then you can use libimobiledevice to move the files. I'd recommend installing it using brew, because it's really nasty to do it manually. https://github.com/libimobiledevice

Comment: @TeresaPeters this should be the accepted answer! Worked like a charm! Btw., you also need to "brew ifuse"